# How to properties from SVN item in repository?

Tags: delphi, svn

I can connect to a repository:

```
var 
   client: TSvnClient;
   url: string;
begin
   BaseDllDir := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'Subversion'; //dlls sitting in "Subversion" folder
   client := TSvnClient.Create;
   client.Initialize;

   url := 'https://repos.wowace.com/wow/bank-items/tags/6.1.0.0';
```

I can use the basic functions of `client.List` to get a list of items:

```
var
   sl: TStrings;
begin
   sl := TStringList.Create;
   client.List(Url, svnDepthImmediates, False, sl);
   Log(sl.Text);
```

And that returns me the list of the item itself, and its immediate files and directory entries:

```
.=/tags/6.1.0.0
.pkgmeta=/tags/6.1.0.0/.pkgmeta
BankItems.lua=/tags/6.1.0.0/BankItems.lua
BankItems.toc=/tags/6.1.0.0/BankItems.toc
Bindings.xml=/tags/6.1.0.0/Bindings.xml
localization-deDE.lua=/tags/6.1.0.0/localization-deDE.lua
localization-enUS.lua=/tags/6.1.0.0/localization-enUS.lua
...snip...
```

I can also use a `TSvnList.LoadList` to get a list of `TSvnListItem` objects:

```
var
   list: TSvnList;
   item: TSvnListItem;
begin
   list := TSvnList.Create(client);
   list.LoadList(Url, svnDepthImmediates, False);

    s := '';
    for i := 0 to list.Count-1 do
begin
    li := list.Items[i];

    s := s+
          '- Item '+intToStr(i)+#13#10+
          '   - **Path**: '+li.Path+#13#10+
          '   - **AbsolutePath**: '+li.AbsolutePath+#13#10+
          '   - **Size**: '+IntToStr(li.Size)+#13#10+
          '   - **Kind**: '+SvnNodeKindString(li.Kind)+#13#10+
          '   - **HasProps**: '+IfThen(li.HasProps, 'Yes', 'No')+#13#10+
          '   - **LastAuthor**: '+li.LastAuthor+#13#10+
          '   - **Time**: '+DateTimeToStr(li.Time)+#13#10+
          '   - **CreatedRevision**: '+IntToStr(li.CreatedRevision)+#13#10+#13#10;
end;
Log(s);
```

> - Item 0
>
>   - **Path**:
>   - **AbsolutePath**: /tags/6.1.0.0
>   - **Size**: 0
>   - **Kind**: svnNodeDir
>   - **HasProps**: No
>   - **LastAuthor**: nbluewiz
>   - **Time**: 2/25/2015 10:13:29 PM
>   - **CreatedRevision**: 227
> - Item 1
>
>   - **Path**: .pkgmeta
>   - **AbsolutePath**: /tags/6.1.0.0
>   - **Size**: 22
>   - **Kind**: svnNodeFile
>   - **HasProps**: No
>   - **LastAuthor**: root
>   - **Time**: 9/29/2008 5:33:49 PM
>   - **CreatedRevision**: 96
> - Item 2
>
>   - **Path**: BankItems.lua
>   - **AbsolutePath**: /tags/6.1.0.0
>   - **Size**: 272471
>   - **Kind**: svnNodeFile
>   - **HasProps**: Yes
>   - **LastAuthor**: burstroc
>   - **Time**: 2/8/2015 11:46:51 PM
>   - **CreatedRevision**: 225
> - Item 3
>
>   - **Path**: BankItems.toc
>   - **AbsolutePath**: /tags/6.1.0.0
>   - **Size**: 1776
>   - **Kind**: svnNodeFile
>   - **HasProps**: Yes
>   - **LastAuthor**: burstroc
>   - **Time**: 2/25/2015 9:02:47 PM
>   - **CreatedRevision**: 226
>
> ...snip...

Which is a long way of saying that i can successfully connect to a repository and query things.

### Now for properties

Now i want to read [some properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980679/reading-svnexternals-from-working-copy) from items in the repository; or some more advanced metadata.

You notice that `TSvnListItem` class has a `HasProps` property; but no way to read the properties. For that i ***think*** we need the `TSvnItem` object:

```
TSvnItem = class
public
   //...snip...
   property SvnPathName: string;
   property URL: string;
   property Parent: TSvnItem;
   property PathName: string;
   property LastCommitAuthor: string;
   property LastCommitRevision: Integer;
   property LastCommitTime: TDateTime;
   property PropCount: Integer;
   property PropNames[Index: Integer]: string;
   property HistoryCount: Integer;
   property HistoryItems[Index: Integer]: TSvnHistoryItem;
end;
```

Given an arbitrary item, it sure would be nice to get the URL of its parent. Or to get the history, or the properties:

```
item := TSvnItem.Create(client, Url);
s := '';
for i := 0 to item.PropCount-1 do
begin
   s := s+'"'+item.PropNames[i]+'" = "'+item.PropValueFromIndex[i]+'"'+#13#10;
end;
Log(s);
```

Except that any attempt to access anything using `TSvnItem` results in the error:

> C:\Program Files(x86)\Contoso\Grobber is not a working copy.

Which is true; it isn't.

There are other overloads of `TSvnItem.Create`, one of which is [used here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980679/reading-svnexternals-from-working-copy) with apparent success:

```
item := TSvnItem.Create(client, nil, Url);
```

But that constructor fails with:

> The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters

It fails inside the constructor on:

```
FSvnPathName := FSvnClient.NativePathToSvnPath(FPathName, SubPool);
```

Which in turn fails at

```
function TSvnClient.NativePathToSvnPath(const NativePath: string; SubPool: PAprPool = nil): string;    
begin
   //...snip...
   AprCheck(apr_filepath_merge(SvnPath, '', PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(NativePath)), APR_FILEPATH_TRUENAME, SubPool));
```

And so i'm stumped. With no documention on the Delphi Svn library i'm...stumped.

### Minimal reproducible example

The Url is public and open for anyone to use:

> https://repos.wowace.com/wow/bank-items/tags/6.1.0.0/BankItems.lua

But you will have to be sure to supply all the Dlls:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses System.SysUtils, SvnClient;

var
  client: TSvnClient;
  item: TSvnItem;
begin
  try
     client := TSvnClient.Create;
     BaseDllDir := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
     client.Initialize;
     item := TSvnItem.Create(client, nil, 'https://repos.wowace.com/wow/bank-items/tags/6.1.0.0/BankItems.lua');
     Writeln('ItemCount: '+IntToStr(item.PropCount));
  except
     on E: Exception do
        Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the comment above the URL overload in SvnClient (1.9).

> { TSvnItem for URLs is some kind of a hack and right now don't expect
>   anything else to work than asynchronous history loading }
>   constructor Create(ASvnClient: TSvnClient; const AURL: string); overload;

It does work with Working Dir

```
procedure TForm1.btLoadPropClick(Sender: TObject);
const 
  url = 'svn://hub/vcl/Trunk/Jedi/';
  WorkDir = 'D:\VCL\Jedi';
var
  i: Integer;
  item: TSvnItem;
begin
  item := TSvnItem.Create(FClient, nil, WorkDir);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('============== Props ============================');
  for i := 0 to Pred(item.PropCount) do begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(item.PropNames[i] + '" = "' + item.PropValueFromIndex[i]);
  end;
  item.Free;
end;
```

Edit:
There seems to be a bug in TSvnItem.ReloadProps on line 2085:

Changing line 2085 to the code below seems to solve the issue:

```
        AprCheck(apr_filepath_merge(TruePath, PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(URL)), PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(FPathName)), APR_FILEPATH_TRUENAME, SubPool));
```